# Fail to call ones or eye function when using RcppArmadillo

Tags: rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I want to use `one` or `eye` function in `Armadillo` to construct matrices or vectors. However, it does not allow me to do so. Here is a sample code:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP Generate(arma::mat Mat){
arma::mat Mat_2 = ones<mat>(5,6);
}
```

error message reminds me of `use of undeclared idenfier of 'mat'`.  When I remove `<mat>`, another massage says `use of undeclared idenfier of 'ones'`.

I looked up the Armadillo tutorial which includes the `ones` function. I wonder why my code fails to call it. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code:

- Why return `SEXP`? Use types to your advantage
- Why pass `Mat` in if you do not use it?
- No `return` statement
- Somewhat loose use of namespaces.

A cleaned up version follows:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat Generate(int n=5, int k=6){
    arma::mat m = arma::ones<arma::mat>(n,k);
    return m;
}

/*** R
Generate()
*/
```

It compiles and runs fine:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/67006975/answer.cpp")

> Generate()
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
[5,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
>
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting me! It does help a lot!